# Retrive html tag content using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the plain text of a website article using python. I've heard about the BeautifulSoup library, but how to retrieve a specific tag in html page?

This is what I have done:

```
base_url = 'http://www.nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. You can have a look at some tutorials (like https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/) and the documentation of BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look this:

```py
import bs4 as bs
import requests as rq

html = rq.get('site.com')

s = bs.BeautifulSoup(html.text, features="html.parser")
div = s.find('div', {'class': 'yourclass'}) # or id

print(str(div.text)) # print text
```

Comment: Ciao Giacomo, grazie mille, funziona